# Can I prove that a 2-variable limit does not exists if the limit on a curve is infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, infinity

Consider a 2 variable function $f(x,y)$ and the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$$

If I find two continuous functions $\gamma_1(t)$ and $\gamma_2(t)$ such that $\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_2(0)=(0,0)$ and

$$\lim_{t\to 0} f(\gamma_1(t))=l \in \mathbb{R} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, and  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \lim_{t\to 0} f(\gamma_2(t))=+\infty $$

Can I conclude that the original limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist?

I'm not sure about this because of the infinity in one of the two limits above

Comment: yes of course it doesn't exist !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it suffices to find, at least, two different limits finite or infinite, for different paths as for example for

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^3-y^3} $$

we have

- $\frac{xy}{x^3-y^3} \to 0$ for $x=0$
- $\frac{xy}{x^3-y^3} \to +\infty$ for $y=-x=t \to 0^+$